# Extending sylius order model in own bundle leads to "target-entity cannot be found" in Adjustment model

Tags: php, symfony, sylius

I have followed http://docs.sylius.org/en/latest/bundles/general/overriding_models.html and tried to extend order model with new field "qrCode"

Entity/Order.php

```
<?php

namespace Funlife\Bundle\EshopBundle\Entity;

use Sylius\Component\Order\Model\Order as BaseOrder;

class Order extends BaseOrder{
    private $qrCode;

    public function getQrCode()
    {
        return $this->qrCode;
    }

    public function setNewQrCode($qrcode)
    {
        $this->qrCode = $qrcode;
    }
}
```

Resources/config/doctrine/Order.orm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping"
                  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
                  xsi:schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping
                                      http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">

    <entity name="Funlife\Bundle\EshopBundle\Entity\Order" table="sylius_order">
        <field name="qrCode" column="qrCode" type="string" length="255" nullable="false" unique="true" />
    </entity>

</doctrine-mapping>
```

config.yml

```
sylius_order:
    driver: doctrine/orm
    classes:
        order:
            model: Funlife\Bundle\EshopBundle\Entity\Order
```

And upon updating database I got following error:

```
[Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\MappingException]                                                                                        
  The target-entity Funlife\Bundle\EshopBundle\Entity\Order cannot be found in 'Sylius\Component\Order\Model\Adjustment#order'.
```

Does anyone know how to get pass this problem? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried this:  %kernel.root_dir%/../src/Funlife/Bundle/EshopBundle/Entity/Order

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and just run `php composer.phar update` and it helped.
My entity was then displayed in mapping info